# Как реализовать на Java вероятность 0.7  вывода в консоль true или false?

Tags: java

Добрый день, не могу понять, как реализовать вероятность 0.7 вывода одного из двух вариантов true либо false. Помогите советом. :-)

Comment: `random.Next(10) < 7`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вопрос неконкретный. В общем случае, если выводить подряд каждые 7 раз true, и каждые 3 раза - false, то на больших количествах выводов будет достигнута вероятность появления true - 0.7. Если нужна псевдослучайная последовательность, то

```
Random r = new Random ();

while (true) {
    System.out.println(r.nextInt(10) < 7 ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Comment: спасибо, точно)

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(Math.random()<0.7);`